# traverse an ontology using dotnetrdf

Tags: sparql, ontology, owl, dotnetrdf

I have created an ontology using protege. Now I want to write a code to traverse ontology using dotNetRDF. By mean of traverse is displaying all classes, sub-classes etc.

I am using following code but it is giving exception **

> The Namespace URI for the given Prefix 'owl' is not known by the
>   in-scope NamespaceMapper

```
OntologyGraph g = new OntologyGraph();
        FileLoader.Load(g, "humanontordf.owl");

        OntologyClass classOfClasses = g.CreateOntologyClass(g.CreateUriNode("owl:Class"));

        //This iterates over the things that are a class
        foreach (OntologyResource r in classOfClasses.Instances)
        {
            //Do what you want with the class
            Console.WriteLine(r.ToString());
        }
```

This code is base on answer given [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130902055057/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19984/dotnetrdf-list-all-ontology-classes) (http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/19984/dotnetrdf-list-all-ontology-classes)

Can anyone let me know what am I missing in above code? any good URL for tutorial on dotNetRDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to the following part of your code:

```
g.CreateUriNode("owl:Class")
```

This uses a prefixed name as a shortcut for the full URI which requires the `owl` prefix to be defined in your graph.

If you are getting this then your RDF file does not include this, you can define this like so:

```
g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("prefix", new Uri("http://some/namespace/"));
```

I guess an `OntologyGraph` should really define the OWL namespace automatically, I'll add this in the next release.

Comment: Added in commit https://bitbucket.org/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/commits/d87aeb97f5df63c78bfcbe3f32a920d0b06da492

Comment: thanks for your reply but it didn't work. I have generated ontology using Protege with RDF/XML.

Comment: between I added following line g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("prefix", new Uri("http://www.qasimpasta.info/humanonto.owl#"));

Comment: It worked when added 

g.NamespaceMap.AddNamespace("owl", UriFactory.Create(NamespaceMapper.OWL));

Comment: @mqpasta The answer given was an example, you need to define the prefix you actually want to use, `prefix` was simply a placeholder for the example